# Template language is not being rendered with html

Tags: html, django

I am new to Django and learning for the first time. I am following a tutorial from youtube. While working with one example given by instructor in video when I tried to imitate that on my system then it isn't working as expected. 
Following is the html file which I want to render.

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block content %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
    <head> 
    </head> 
   <body> 
    <h1>Hellow World!</h1>
     <p>
     This is <code> { % verbatim % } {{ html_var }} { % endverbatim % } 
      </code> html coming through
     </p> 

<p>
    { % if num is not None %}
    Random number is: {{ num }}
    { % endif % }
</p>

    <p>
    { % for some_item in some_list % }
    { % if some_item | divisibleby = "2" % }
    Even number 

    {{some_item }} 

    <br>
    { % % }
    { % endfor % }</p>
   <p>Some item is {{ some_item }}</p>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock content %}
```

and output is the following:
MuyPicky.com
Home About Contact
Hellow World!
This is { % verbatim % } { % endverbatim % } html coming through

{ % if num is not None %} Random number is: { % endif % }

{ % for some_item in some_list % } { % if some_item | divisibleby = "2" % } Even number 
{ %% } { % endfor % }

Some item is
My problem is like why "{ % for some_item in some_list % }" these things are being rendered as it as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have spaces between `{` and `%` in Django tags.

It should be:

```
{% if num is not None %} Random number is: {% endif %}
```

etc.